# Compare the similarity of character vectors by position

Tags: r

I have the following dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(barcode=c("B1","B2", "B3", "B4"), 
                 sequence= sapply(1:4, function(x) paste(sample(c("A","C","T","G"), 4, replace=T), collapse="")))
```

I want to know how similar each 'barcode' is compared to any other 'barcode' in df$barcode. That is, by position.

A complete agreement would be 100%, one position in disagreement would be 75% and so on.

Example:
df$barcode contains (AATT, AATT, TATT, TATA)

the pairwise similarity matrix would be then

```
 B1 B2 B3 B4
B1 x 100 75 50
B2 100 x 75 50
B3 75 75 x 75
B4 50 50 75 x
```

even though every 'Barcode" contains 2xT and 2xA. So, the question is "how many positions have the same content between two Barcodes?"
How to achieve this in R?

Comment: Your code for data generation does not work.

Comment: Sorry, corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Levenshtein (edit) distance, or rather 1-distance

```
> 1-adist(df$sequence)/4

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] 1.00 0.75 0.25 0.25
[2,] 0.75 1.00 0.00 0.25
[3,] 0.25 0.00 1.00 0.50
[4,] 0.25 0.25 0.50 1.00
```

(assuming all lengths equal to 4).

**Edit:** I misunderstood your problem. Levenshtein distance finds maximal matching, so reordering the strings if necessary. You want an exact word for word matching, in that case...

```
sapply(df$sequence,function(x){
  sapply(df$sequence,function(y){
    sum(strsplit(x,"")[[1]]==strsplit(y,"")[[1]])
  })
})/4

     ACAC AGAC CCTT CGCT
ACAC 1.00 0.75 0.25 0.00
AGAC 0.75 1.00 0.00 0.25
CCTT 0.25 0.00 1.00 0.50
CGCT 0.00 0.25 0.50 1.00
```

or for the other vector provided in the comments

```
sapply(df$sequence,function(x){
  sapply(df$sequence,function(y){
    sum(strsplit(x,"")[[1]]==strsplit(y,"")[[1]])
  })
})/4

     GACC AAAC ACAC GCCA
GACC 1.00 0.50 0.25 0.50
AAAC 0.50 1.00 0.75 0.00
ACAC 0.25 0.75 1.00 0.25
GCCA 0.50 0.00 0.25 1.00
```

Comment: Witg GACC, AAAC, ACAC, GCCA, your code yielded 1.0 0.50 0.50 0.50, but GACC vs ACAC should be 0.25, or?

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/6bpjyx8/111t.jpg

Comment: @nouse, hard to replicate with your sample dataset, every time you run it you get different outcome ;) GACC and ACAC was your sampling. Stick please to your fixed (AATT, AATT, TATT, TATA) example and you will see the given answer works.

Comment: @MerijnvanTilborg - the answer here gives the right result on the original data incidentally. But as OP states, it gives the wrong result on other data - this is because the Levenshtein distance is not the right method to use.  It requires one deletion and one insertion to turn GACC to ACAC (0.5) where OP wants to know how many letters are in the same place (0.25).  Instead, OP can use `stringdist::stringsimmatrix(df$sequence, method = "hamming", useNames = "strings")`.

Comment: Fair enough, I was wrong there in my conclusion. However it is advisable to make sample data not dynamic as everyone starting to help starts with a different dataset and different outcomes.